# Can't find table(s) lexeme_norm for language 'en' in spacy-lookups-data

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, spacy-3, spacy-transformers

I want to train new NER entities with the following code:

```
def train_spacy_model(data, model='en_core_web_trf', n_iter=50):
    if model is not None:
        nlp = spacy.load(model)  # load existing spaCy model
        print("Loaded model '%s'" % model)
        
    TRAIN_DATA = data
    ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")
    
    examples = []
    for text, annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
        examples.append(Example.from_dict(nlp.make_doc(text), annotations))
    nlp.initialize(lambda: examples)
    
    pipe_exceptions = ["ner"]
    other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe not in pipe_exceptions]
    with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train NER

        for itn in range(n_iter):
            random.shuffle(examples)
            losses = {}
            batches = minibatch(examples, size=compounding(4.0, 64.0, 1.2))
            for batch in batches:
                texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
                nlp.update(
                    batch,  
                    drop=0.20, 
                    losses=losses
                   
                )
            print("Losses", losses)
    
    return nlp

nlp = train_spacy_model(data=dataset, n_iter=30)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[296], line 40
     36             print("Losses", losses)
     38     return nlp
---> 40 nlp = train_spacy_model(data=no_verlaps_dataset, n_iter=30)
     42 # save model to output directory
     43 output_dir = '_data/models/actor_ner'

Cell In[296], line 16, in train_spacy_model(data, model, n_iter)
     14 for text, annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
     15     examples.append(Example.from_dict(nlp.make_doc(text), annotations))
---> 16 nlp.initialize(lambda: examples)
     17     # for ent in annotations.get('entities'):
     18     #     ner.add_label(ent[2])
     20 pipe_exceptions = ["ner", "trf_wordpiecer", "trf_tok2vec"]

File ~/miniconda3/envs/tvman_ENV/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/language.py:1290, in Language.initialize(self, get_examples, sgd)
   1288 config = self.config.interpolate()
   1289 # These are the settings provided in the [initialize] block in the config
-> 1290 I = registry.resolve(config["initialize"], schema=ConfigSchemaInit)
   1291 before_init = I["before_init"]
   1292 if before_init is not None:

File ~/miniconda3/envs/tvman_ENV/lib/python3.9/site-packages/thinc/config.py:746, in registry.resolve(cls, config, schema, overrides, validate)
    737 @classmethod
    738 def resolve(
    739     cls,
   (...)
    744     validate: bool = True,
    745 ) -> Dict[str, Any]:
--> 746     resolved, _ = cls._make(
    747         config, schema=schema, overrides=overrides, validate=validate, resolve=True
    748     )
    749     return resolved

File ~/miniconda3/envs/tvman_ENV/lib/python3.9/site-packages/thinc/config.py:795, in registry._make(cls, config, schema, overrides, resolve, validate)
    793 if not is_interpolated:
    794     config = Config(orig_config).interpolate()
--> 795 filled, _, resolved = cls._fill(
    796     config, schema, validate=validate, overrides=overrides, resolve=resolve
    797 )
    798 filled = Config(filled, section_order=section_order)
    799 # Check that overrides didn't include invalid properties not in config

File ~/miniconda3/envs/tvman_ENV/lib/python3.9/site-packages/thinc/config.py:867, in registry._fill(cls, config, schema, validate, resolve, parent, overrides)
    864     getter = cls.get(reg_name, func_name)
    865     # We don't want to try/except this and raise our own error
    866     # here, because we want the traceback if the function fails.
--> 867     getter_result = getter(*args, **kwargs)
    868 else:
    869     # We're not resolving and calling the function, so replace
    870     # the getter_result with a Promise class
    871     getter_result = Promise(
    872         registry=reg_name, name=func_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs
    873     )

File ~/miniconda3/envs/tvman_ENV/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/language.py:108, in load_lookups_data(lang, tables)
    105 @registry.misc("spacy.LookupsDataLoader.v1")
    106 def load_lookups_data(lang, tables):
    107     util.logger.debug(f"Loading lookups from spacy-lookups-data: {tables}")
--> 108     lookups = load_lookups(lang=lang, tables=tables)
    109     return lookups

File ~/miniconda3/envs/tvman_ENV/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/lookups.py:30, in load_lookups(lang, tables, strict)
     28 if lang not in registry.lookups:
     29     if strict and len(tables) > 0:
---> 30         raise ValueError(Errors.E955.format(table=", ".join(tables), lang=lang))
     31     return lookups
     32 data = registry.lookups.get(lang)

ValueError: [E955] Can't find table(s) lexeme_norm for language 'en' in spacy-lookups-data. Make sure you have the package installed or provide your own lookup tables if no default lookups are available for your language.
```

I have installed the package:

```
pip install spacy-lookups-data
Collecting spacy-lookups-data
  Downloading spacy_lookups_data-1.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (98.5 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 98.5/98.5 MB 25.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
```

But it still persists.

How can I fix this error to commence updating the model to detect new entitities for ner tasks?

EDIT
It got fixed when I restarted the kernel in jupyter notbook that this code ran in.

Comment: Just to back up here a bit, have you tried doing training using the config like the docs recommend? How did you write this training loop? Writing your own training loop has instead can cause in general, but even putting that aside the `trf_wordpiecer` in your code here is from old versions of spacy-transformers and isn't used any more - it was gone in 1.0, which was released Feb 2021.

Comment: @polm23 Thanks for your response. Actually I need only the ''ner" part. I want to do this simple step programatically. I do not want to use CLI. As I run it in jupyter notebook when I restarted the kernel the issue stopped.

Comment: If you don't want to use the CLI you still don't have to write your own training loop, you can just use the `train` function, see this link. For reference, why don't you want to use the CLI? https://spacy.io/usage/training#api

Comment: @polm23 I did not want to use CLI as I do not need additional framework' files in my project. Anyway can you share some example code how can I add my own NER entities so that `en_core_web_trf` can recognize them? I find it hard to understand how such code should look like. I'm new to Spacy3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been running this code in Jupyter Notebook and the error persisted until I restarted the kernel. So the answer is to restart the notebook kernel.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the narrow question: you probably need to restart your runtime in order for the tables in `spacy-lookups-data` to be registered.

---

To answer the question you didn't ask: the quoted script looks like it was only partially updated from v2 and I wouldn't recommend using it, in particular not for `en_core_web_trf`. One recommended way to update `ner` components in spacy v3 pipelines is shown in this demo project:

https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/pipelines/ner_demo_update

It handles a lot of the pipeline/config/training details for you in order to update `ner` without affecting the performance of the other components in the pipeline. A walkthrough of how to run a project is shown in the [v2->v3 examples README](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/tree/18ffe5bbd6a554920107ff48d1387df34c3f872a/examples).

Comment: Can you please provide actual code that address the issue that you mention as I can't find the answer to my question under the links  that you provided.